# Error in loading full attributes panel in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, plugins, ide

I have done everything to make attributes panel show its full settings (eg. for a button) but in vain.

I am a newbie and i want this panel for easy understanding of the android studio at first.

Things i have tried so far:

1. Tried clearing the cache by going to : file->invalidate cache
2. Tried syncing project with gradlefiles
3. Tried installing version 3.0.1
4. Tried reinstalling android studio 3.1 *{4 times from scratch}*

**p.s. i am using android studio version 3.1 and android marshmallow as OS (api level 23)**

[FOR BETTER UNDERSTANDING YOU CAN SEE THE IMAGE HERE {PIC->1}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuIEj.png)

[AND HERE {PIC->2}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DXbE.png)

[WHEN CLICKING AT "**VIEW ALL ATTRIBUTES**" AT RIGHT BOTTOM CORNER {PIC->3}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EUF5.png)

The error i am getting is :

```
null java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.getRenderResult(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:602)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.ScreenViewBase.getResult(ScreenViewBase.java:109)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.ScreenView.getResult(ScreenView.java:30)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.menu.NavigationViewSceneView.getPreferredSize(NavigationViewSceneView.java:64)
at com.android.tools.idea.common.surface.SceneView.getPreferredSize(SceneView.java:95)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.createSceneViewsForMenu(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:265)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.doCreateSceneView(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:234)
at com.android.tools.idea.common.scene.SceneManager.createSceneView(SceneManager.java:73)
at com.android.tools.idea.common.scene.SceneManager.<init>(SceneManager.java:66)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.<init>(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:157)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.NlDesignSurface.createSceneManager(NlDesignSurface.java:145)
at com.android.tools.idea.common.surface.DesignSurface.setModel(DesignSurface.java:281)
at com.android.tools.idea.common.editor.NlEditorPanel.initNeleModelOnEventDispatchThread(NlEditorPanel.java:143)
at com.android.tools.idea.common.editor.NlEditorPanel.lambda$null$4(NlEditorPanel.java:139)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.lambda$smartInvokeLater$7(DumbServiceImpl.java:366)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:424)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

If anyone knows what's the problem or what should i **"reinstall"** it would be a great help. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue.

**Here is the fix**: In the Attributes pane, click the More Options icon (cog in the upper right) and select **All attributes table**. That will "restore" things. The other option there is **XML attribute editor**. I don't know how my IDE got switched to **XML**, but once I changed it back to **All** everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

**To view attribute of each follow steps given in screen shots**

[image: First step]

[image: After opening attribute tab]

Comment: Chetan, thanks for your answer but I have tried this already!!

Comment: There is a hyperlink of view all attribute as you shown in image try to click on this and watch what happens

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chetan, but I have already done it as you can see in the pic above in the question itself, listed as PIC-3 and again thanks for your support.....

Comment: @yogeshdhiman then this is different problem. Sorry for that.

Comment: Chetan, there is no need to be sorry, as we can see nobody has given an answer except you and this is an important feature to me, can you suggest some other way (eg. some site I should visit) through which I can solve this problem it will be a great help!!!! I have installed android studio 10 times now (from scratch) and I get the same problem everytime......

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I tried everything even installing a fresh copy of Android Studio on my friends laptop and copying the healthy files(which were different from mine...) from there and pasting them in my laptop at appropriate positions, but even this didn't work.

The only option left with me was to reinstall windows so that worked for me! If some other thing worked for somebody please feel free to post.

Thanks in advance !!